# pandas (horizontal) stacked bars, with per-bar segment sorting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I can produce horizontal stacked bars from a multi-index dataframe with this code:

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve'])]

s = abs(pd.Series(np.random.randn(12), index=arrays))

ax = s.unstack(level=1).plot.barh(stacked=True, colormap='Paired')

plt.show()
```

this outputs

[image: horizontal stacked bars]

but I would like the *largest segment on each bar* (regardless of category) to always appear at the base of the bar (*i*.*e*. on the left). I haven't found any parameters for `barh()` that do the trick, and sorting `s` on level 0 doesn't help given the `unstack`-ing.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose? Since you're mixing groups within bars?

Comment: which purpose? :) also, in my particular data the categories on every bar are all different from the ones on the other bars (maybe I should change my example to make that clearer)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ example updated!

Comment: Love the colours... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`matplotlib.barh`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html) directly:

```
barh(range(4), ax.sum(axis=1), color=['blue' if one else 'green' for one in ax.one == ax.max(axis=1)]);
barh(range(4), ax.max(axis=1), color=['green' if one else 'blue' for one in ax.one == ax.max(axis=1)]);
```

[image]

Of course you can make the ticks and labels nicer with `yticks` and so.

---

**Edit**

For the general case, here's an outline on how to expand things scalably.

First, start with

```
d = s.unstack(level=1).as_matrix()
```

Now iterate until `np.nansum(d) == 0`.

For each iteration, the lengths of the bars should be

```
np.nansum(d, axis=1)
```

To get the colors to plot, you can use

```
np.nanargmin(d, axis=1)
```

(you need to map these numbers to colors). At the end of each iteration, use

```
d[:, np.nanargmin(d, axis=1)] = np.nan
```

This will plot shorter bars on top of longer bars, giving the illusion of stacked bars.

Comment: thanks! there's up to a dozen different categories/colors for each bar. I see this not scaling very nicely even with  three categories, but maybe I'm wrong. are you aware of something that wouldn't depend on knowing even the number of categories but only their size?

Comment: I really don't see the problem with scaling it (except for the question of whether the human eye scales to it that well). You simply draw in a loop the sum of all columns, all columns except smallest (per row), all columns except two smallest (per row), and adjust the color accordingly. With 15.4K rep you should be able to figure it out :-)

Comment: I agree partially with your other comment - I may have simplified the example a bit too much. I've updated my question! Thanks!

Comment: For anyone seeing this answer - note that my initial example was simpler and used the colors used by Ami. I updated the example in my question to avoid any further confusion, but this solution actually worked in specific cases!

Comment: Have updated the answer with an outline of the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Since the dataframe is pretty sparse, i.e. only one value per column, you may just sort the columns by that value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve'])]

s = abs(pd.Series(np.random.randn(12), index=arrays))
df = s.unstack(level=1)
df = df[df.columns[np.argsort(df.sum())[::-1]]]
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True, colormap='Paired')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but I think the extreme sparsity was just an example.

Comment: Well, feel free to keep chaning the use case after each obtained answer.

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest - Hey, I'm not the author of the question. Here's an upvote for your answer (I liked it).

Comment: Haha, sorry. I guess the principle of the other answer still works in more general cases, if you use `numpy.cumsum`.

Comment: No problem. BTW, I don't quite see how `cumsum` would solve it, but outlined how to do it with `np.nanargmin` and `np.nansum`.